# i am using nextjs as frontend and the backend developer is creating the api differently in express and mysql ,How to protect the routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, middleware

I am working as a frontend developer ,I am new to nextjs and dont know that much ,The backend developer has been assigned to create the api in express and mysql ,on successful login I receive accessToken ,but the problem is I dont understand how to protect the preauthPage (How to not be able to show the preauth login/signup pages) once the user has successfully logged into the account please help me out I am stuck from  3 days
I tried to use middleware.ts file in nextjs but it is subtly not working correctly

Comment: https://dev.to/codebeast/how-to-protect-nextjs-13-app-routes-with-authentication-1bjh See here, using useRouter and upadte route on access token response

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you can set accessToken in the sessionStorage on successfull login and render the page conditionally then get accessToken from the sessionStorage if it is set then show the page otherwise navigate to home page

Answer (score 0):

To protect the preauth pages in your Next.js application after the user has successfully logged in, you can use a combination of session management and route guards. Here's how to implement it:

1. **Session Management**: Store the user's authentication status and access token in session storage or a cookie after a successful login.
2. **Route Guards**: Create a higher-order component (HOC) or a custom hook to check the user's authentication status before rendering protected routes. Redirect the user to the login page if they are not authenticated.

First, create a custom hook to handle authentication checks:

```js
// hooks/useAuth.js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const useAuth = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');

    if (!accessToken) {
      // Redirect to login page if access token is not present
      router.push('/login');
    }
  }, []);

  return;
};

export default useAuth;
```

Next, use this hook in your protected pages:

```js
// pages/protectedPage.js
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';

const ProtectedPage = () => {
  useAuth();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Protected Page</h1>
      {/* Add your protected page content here */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProtectedPage;
```

Finally, update your login page to set the access token in session storage or a cookie after a successful login:

```js
// pages/login.js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const LoginPage = () => {
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState('');
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleLogin = () => {
    // Perform login logic and get access token
    // For example, call your API and receive the access token

    // Store the access token in session storage or cookie
    localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);

    // Redirect to protected page
    router.push('/protectedPage');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login Page</h1>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter access token"
        value={accessToken}
        onChange={(e) => setAccessToken(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

With this setup, the `useAuth` hook will ensure that only authenticated users can access the protected pages. If a user tries to access a protected page without being authenticated, they will be redirected to the login page.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply . but what do when a user is logged in and he  wanted to access  http://localhost:3000/login ,any way can i connect to you ?